# How to minimize a sidebarLayout in a Shiny App?

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

I am building a shiny app and I am using two sidebarLayouts. I’m looking for a way to minimize them. I have try put each sidebarLayout into a box.

**Example code:**

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  headerPanel("Here goes the heder"),
  box(sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(textOutput("someinputs")),
          
          mainPanel(textOutput("someoutputs"))),
          
          width = 12,
          title = "BB",
          collapsible = T,
          collapsed = F
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$someinputs <- renderText({
    "Here will go the inputs"
  })
  
  output$someoutputs <- renderText({
    "Here will go the outputs"
  })
  
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Output:**[image: Result]
When I press the collapsible button the Layout does not collapse. **Why is this happening? What should I do? Is there other way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't use `shinydashboard`. The box comes from `shinydashboard` package. You need to use `shinydashboard::dashboardPage` instead of `fluidPage`.
`dashboardPage` Loads required javascripts and CSS files to toggle the button.

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
    shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(),
    shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(),
    shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
        headerPanel("Here goes the heder"),
        shinydashboard::box(
            width = 12,
            title = "BB",
            collapsible = TRUE,
            collapsed = FALSE,
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(textOutput("someinputs")),
                mainPanel(textOutput("someoutputs")))
        ) 
    )
)
```

If you don't want to use `dashboardPage`, you can write your own scripts to control the button:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    headerPanel("Here goes the heder"),
    shinydashboard::box(
        width = 12,
        title = "BB",
        collapsible = TRUE,
        collapsed = FALSE,
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(textOutput("someinputs")),
            mainPanel(textOutput("someoutputs")))
    )%>% {.$attribs[['id']] <- 'example-box'; .},
    tags$head(tags$script(
        "$(document).ready(function(){
          $('#example-box button').attr({
            'data-toggle':'collapse', 
            'data-target':'#example-box .box-body', 
            'aria-expanded':false
          })
        })"
    ))
)
```

I used a hack to assign an ID to the box `%>% {.$attribs[['id']] <- 'example-box'; .}`, and use some jquery to control the button. Be sure the ID in the script matches the ID you assign in UI, `example-box` in this case. In javascript, you add `#` for ID searching, so `#example-box`.

I wouldn't recommend you to use the second way. You can see in your UI, it's not really a box. It has no border and the button is not at the right place. If you use `dashboardPage`, you can see the difference. [image: box]